# I want to Change Date Format

Tags: java, android

> I want to change date 3 7 2015 to 3Aug 2015

I have Date Value Like :

```
int day=3,month =7 ,year =2015
```

Comment: have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Okay. What did your review of the API documentation and web searches find? What did your code trying to use that information look like? What results did it give that you didn't expect?

Comment: just user the following format dd MMM YYYY, it will convert the date to desired format

Comment: Thank You  @SSH its Work Thank you Bro. but how to add My selected date In Today ?

Comment: your today object must have the format in which you have your selected date than you can set your date to today object ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple try below sample code :-

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DateFormatter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(2015, 7, 3);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dMMM yyyy");

        System.out.println("Formatted Date :  " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Formatted Date :  3Aug 2015
```

Answer (score 1):

This is utilizing the new [date and formatter classes in Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html):

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.JULY, 3);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dMMM yyyy");
String formattedDateTime = date.format(formatter); // "3Aug 2015"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a real Date object and then format it:

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 3);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("DD_MMM_YYYY");
format.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: That's an exemple with full Java from JDK before Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Convert all the value to string, then concate the value in the following format
// date Month year, then use Simpledateformat as dd MMM yyyy

DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
Date date = originalFormat.parse("3 7 2015");
String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have date values in a variable then you could use an array to get the values of the month.

```
String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
int day = 5;
int month = 4;
int year = 1994;

System.out.printnln("The Date is " + day + months[month - 1]+ year);
```